# Facebook messages could not be sent, is this person blocking me?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I tried to send a friend a message in Facebook and this message popped up:

> Based on the preferences of the person you're trying to contact, this message could not be delivered.

Does that mean my message was blocked?

I searched the Facebook help forums and found one other person had this same issue but didn't receive an answer or clarification

Comment: Yes, the message wasn't delivered, but it doesn't mean that the recipient blocked you. Today I tried to send a message to somebody who just added me and I received the same error reply. So it's either a bug (likely, sometimes, given facebook track record) or a feature (in certain cases).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means your message was blocked. As an experiment you could send again, it you do not receive the same message, it means the first set was a technical error with Facebook.

As Alex mentioned, sometimes there can be bounces.

Answer (score 0):

Your message won't be delivered. and under that second paragraph if you think this doesn't go against our Community Standards let us know.